# Katalon iOS mobile automation, is it possible to make a custom keyword that will long press and move element(drag and drop)

Tags: mobile, appium, katalon-studio

Currently I'm having some problem using Drag and Drop keyword in katalon, since the object that I need to drag should be tapped (for like 1 sec) before it pop-out and be moveable but since the "drag and drop" keyword works instantly without any timeout on the first action (drag). Now has anyone tried using a custom keyword for this kind of issue?

Thank you so much in advance.

Currently this is the only code that I am trying to convert in mobile since it was originally created for web, I'm not very sure if I am doing it right.

```
package aCustomDragmDrop
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords

import internal.GlobalVariable

import MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.By

import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileDriverFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory

import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.RequestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ResponseObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObjectProperty

import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.helper.MobileElementCommonHelper
import com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil

import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction

public class DragDrop {

    @Keyword
    def dragdrop(TestObject to,TestObject destination,Integer intX,Integer intY) {
    def Eleto = MobileElementCommonHelper.findElement(to, timout)
    def eledest = MobileElementCommonHelper.findElement(destination, timeout)   
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver)
    touchAction.moveToElement(eleto)
    touchAction.waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(2000)))
    touchAction.perform()
    touchAction.moveToElement(eledest,intX, intY)
    touchAction.release()
    touchAction.perform();
}
}
```